# Finding a Random number in lua

Tags: random, lua

I am trying to use lua to produce a random number, but it simply spits out the lowest value. For instance, if I run:

```
x = math.random(17,41)  
print(x)
```

It returns:

```
17
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

That is not necessarily true. All random numbers are not entirely random. As an example, you can take a look at this working code; which is the same as you posted in question: http://eval.in/17806

The output as you can see is **38**.

To quote from Doub's reply:

> You can use `math.randomseed` to start the pseudo-random sequence
>   elsewhere. You can use `os.time` to initialize that with a different
>   value every time you run the program (assuming you allow at lease one
>   second to elapse between runs).

Here is an example for the same program with `randomseed` in action: http://eval.in/17808

```
math.randomseed( os.time() )
x = math.random(17,41)  
print(x)
```

Comment: Using math.randomseed( os.time() ) worked the first time I used it, but then kept returning the same value, no matter how many seconds I allowed to elapse between executions. Thoughts?

Comment: @user2218101 Can you provide your code?

Comment: You need to call math.randomseed() before each call to math.random()

Comment: Still, the use of `math.randomseed(os.time())` does not change the fact that a script shortly after the previous one will likely result in exactly the same number or a very similar one. It seems, for a more random solution there is the need of a custom seeded function.

Answer (score 3):

Lua uses the C runtime library pseudo-random number generator. Its properties depend on your platform. For example on (some versions of) Windows, the generator is always initialized at the same point of the pseudo-random sequence, so you always get the same sequence of values when running your program (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/f0d4wb4t.aspx).

You can use math.randomseed to start the pseudo-random sequence elsewhere. You can use os.time to initialize that with a different value every time you run the program (assuming you allow at lease one second to elapse between runs).

Note also that on some Windows C runtime libraries, the first pseudo-random value you get after calling srand (or math.randomseed in Lua) is very dependent on the value you pass. So I would recommend calling math.random once and ignoring its result after calling math.randomseed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you seed the PRNG?

for example, `math.randomseed(os.time())`